# Reading three words and sorting them in lexicographic order

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that asks the User to type three words and sort them in lexicographic order.

EXAMPLE;

> - Enter three words separated by spaces:
> - Pear Orange Apple
> - Apple
> - Orange
> - Pear

The program is working fine (if I attempt the above example) except for one type of combination example that I will show below.

EXAMPLE;

> - Enter three words separated by spaces:
> - Orange Apple Pear
> - Apple
> - Pear
> - Pear

The program is skipping the first word (Orange) if it is supposed to appear in the middle of the three words.

I believe that this line of code is affecting the program because it says that "this assigned value is never used" but I'm not sure how to fix it since I'm still an entry Java learner.

> - middle = firstWord;

Because of that line being unused, it's why Pear appeared twice.

```
import java.util.*;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

Scanner wordInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String firstWord;
String secondWord;
String thirdWord;


System.out.println("Enter three words separated by spaces: ");

firstWord = wordInput.next();
secondWord = wordInput.next();
thirdWord = wordInput.next();


String top = firstWord;
String bottom = firstWord;
if( top.compareTo(secondWord) > 0) 
{ 
top = secondWord; 
} 
if( top.compareTo(thirdWord) > 0) 
{ 
top = thirdWord; 
} 
if( bottom.compareTo(secondWord) < 0) 
{ 
bottom = secondWord; 
} 
if( bottom.compareTo(thirdWord) < 0) 
{ 
bottom = thirdWord; 
}   
String middle;
if( !firstWord.equals(bottom) && !firstWord.equals(top) ) 
{ 
middle = firstWord; 
} 
if( !secondWord.equals(bottom) && !secondWord.equals(top) ) 
{ 
middle = secondWord; 
} 
else 
{ 
middle = thirdWord; 
} 

System.out.println( top ); 
System.out.println( middle ); 
System.out.println( bottom ); 


}
}
```

Does anyone what I am missing or doing wrong? :(
Please and thank you for any help!

Comment: Thanks for the help you guys! 
I really cannot believe how blind I was with the else-if. :( 
My instructor strictly only allowed me to use If-statements, case switches, and/or comparedTo. If I used TreeSet, he would dock my points off, and to be honest, I'm not advanced enough to think that I could use that set of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `else` in selecting the `middle` word: the first `if` correctly assigns `Orange` to it, but then the last `if`/`else` re-assigns `Pear` to it.

Here is how to fix your code:

```
if( !firstWord.equals(bottom) && !firstWord.equals(top) ) {
    middle = firstWord; 
} else if( !secondWord.equals(bottom) && !secondWord.equals(top) ) {
    middle = secondWord; 
}  else  {
    middle = thirdWord; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you dasblinkenlight! This really helped me. I can't believe I missed the Else If.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than adding so much conditions you can simply do this by **TreeSet**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        Scanner wordInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstWord;
        String secondWord;
        String thirdWord;


        System.out.println("Enter three words separated by spaces: ");

        firstWord = wordInput.next();
        secondWord = wordInput.next();
        thirdWord = wordInput.next();

        TreeSet<String> treeSet=new TreeSet<>();

        treeSet.add(firstWord);
        treeSet.add(secondWord);
        treeSet.add(thirdWord);
        for(String s:treeSet){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

And if you have duplicate:

```
    Map<String, Integer> treeMap=new TreeMap<>();
    if(treeMap.containsKey(firstWord)){
        Integer i=treeMap.get(firstWord);
        i++;
        treeMap.put(firstWord, i);
    }
    else{
        treeMap.put(firstWord, 1);
    }
    if(treeMap.containsKey(secondWord)){
        Integer i=treeMap.get(secondWord);
        i++;
        treeMap.put(secondWord, i);
    }
     else{
        treeMap.put(secondWord, 1);
    }
    if(treeMap.containsKey(thirdWord)){
        Integer i=treeMap.get(thirdWord);
        i++;
        treeMap.put(thirdWord, i);
    }
     else{
        treeMap.put(thirdWord, 1);
    }
    for(String s:treeMap.keySet()){
        int k=treeMap.get(s);
        while(k>0){
            System.out.println(s);
            k--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Clever, but what does it print if you enter `Apple Pear Pear`?

Comment: @Gabe it's not too difficult, use TreeMap and count the frequency. You want me to change the code?

Comment: Thanks for the help Trying! I appreciate it but my instructor would refuse the code and just make me remake it. It's a lot simpler in coding though, that's for sure! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with less code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Enter three words separated by spaces: ");
    //Scanner wordsInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Console console = System.console();

    //List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(console.readLine().split("\\s+"));
    Collections.sort(words);
    for (String word : words) {
         System.out.println(String.format("- %s",word));
    }
}
```